Texture Problem When Trying to Render
Very new to Blender. I was trying to add some decals to a car, but while they show in EEVEE, they don't when in Cycles. I don't know if it's a texture, shader, or geometry issue. I applied the texture through the texture editor, the base material was taken from Blenderkit.
When in EEVEE:

When in Cycles:


Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

This is a site run by volunteers answering question for free on their spare time, rushing them or giving deadlines may be discouraging and is generally considered rude. Among other factors, how fast you get answers depends largely on how thorough your question is.

Hello, probably a Z-fighting problem, you may have some faces overlapping, check if this is the case, and if not please share your file
